# Flex-container на разных экранах

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, у меня есть 3 `flex` контейнера в них по 3 `flex` итема, Вопрос как сделать чтобы при открытии страницы на маленьком экране они не просто шли друг за другом а стали в столбик по смысловому типу все первые итемы под первыми вторые под вторыми и тд.

```
<div class =flex-container>
<div class flexitem flexitem-1></div>
<div class flexitem flexitem-2></div>
<div class flexitem flexitem-3></div>
 </div>
<div class =flex-container>
<div class flexitem flexitem-1></div>
<div class flexitem flexitem-2></div>
<div class flexitem flexitem-3></div>
 </div>
<div class =flex-container>
<div class flexitem flexitem-1></div>
<div class flexitem flexitem-2></div>
<div class flexitem flexitem-3></div>
 </div>


.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: лучше нарисовать ожидаемы результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Решение на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0kjswfLe/)

Обратите внимание на то, как пишутся классы `html` элементам, у вас они написаны не правильно.

```css
.flexitem {
  border: solid 1px grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 30%;
}
.flexitem-1 {
  background: lightpink;
}
.flexitem-2 {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.flexitem-3 {
  background: lightblue;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flexitem flexitem-1">1</div>
  <div class="flexitem flexitem-2">2</div>
  <div class="flexitem flexitem-3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flexitem flexitem-1">1</div>
  <div class="flexitem flexitem-2">2</div>
  <div class="flexitem flexitem-3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flexitem flexitem-1">1</div>
  <div class="flexitem flexitem-2">2</div>
  <div class="flexitem flexitem-3">3</div>
</div>
```